ZFS dataset encryption on top of LUKS
There has been discussions about using ZFS on top of a LUKS-encrypted partition vs. using ZFS's native per-dataset encryption. However, they are always presented as either-or.
My question is about using both: making a LUKS partition, then using that as a zpool container, then creating ZFS-encrypted datasets in that zpool. That should give no-metadata-leaking encryption at rest while still allowing neat tricks like zfs send-ing encrypted datasets to untrusted backup storage.
In this scenario, what would be the performance impact of this "double encryption" compared to just ZFS native encryption?

Encryption is fast thanks to AESNI but it still occupies your CPU when it could do other work in the same time. If you have plenty CPU resource to spare you might not notice; or it could have an impact. It depends on your use case, so this is really something you should benchmark yourself.

I've done some testing of this, so here are some numbers. Bear in mind this was measured just using the first things I could think of; I'm hoping for other answers with more details.
All testing done with 32G RAM, no swap, and a minimum ARC size of 1G and maximum ARC size of 3G, if that makes a difference.
Using FIO
I've tried fio --refill_buffers --rw=randrw --name=test --size=5G --numjobs=5 and the headline numbers reported are:
ZFS native dataset encryption only
   READ: bw=25.6MiB/s (26.9MB/s), 5252KiB/s-5325KiB/s (5378kB/s-5453kB/s), io=12.5GiB (13.4GB), run=492550-499123msec
  WRITE: bw=25.7MiB/s (26.9MB/s), 5252KiB/s-5320KiB/s (5378kB/s-5447kB/s), io=12.5GiB (13.4GB), run=492550-499123msec


ZFS native dataset encryption on a LUKS-encrypted zpool
   READ: bw=17.5MiB/s (18.4MB/s), 3589KiB/s-3619KiB/s (3676kB/s-3706kB/s), io=12.5GiB (13.4GB), run=724349-729360msec
  WRITE: bw=17.6MiB/s (18.4MB/s), 3596KiB/s-3619KiB/s (3682kB/s-3706kB/s), io=12.5GiB (13.4GB), run=724349-729360msec

So FIO shows substantial bandwidth difference. But I wanted to try something that is closer to real-life usage, so I tried compiling the Glasgow Haskell Compiler 9.8.2 and LLVM 0e5a53cc01e406436cb7c703c84598e474d635de from source.
Compiling GHC 9.8.2
Using Hadrian's built-in profiling facilities, I've run a fresh build with the default settings and 32 threads.
ZFS only
Build time: 3h30m serialized, 25m21s wall time with parallelization. Longest single build rule is GHC/Hs/Instances.p_o in 1m23s.
ZFS over LUKS
Build time: 3h34m serialized, 25m16s wall time with parallelization. Longest single build rule is GHC/Hs/Instances.p_o in 1m23s.
Compiling LLVM
Using default flags, with Ninja builder using 18 compilation threads and 2 linker threads (to avoid running out of memory). I don't know if Ninja has any profiling support, so I just used time.
ZFS only
real    61m40.229s
user    542m57.056s
sys     49m29.346s

ZFS over LUKS
real    61m25.019s
user    542m51.777s
sys     48m58.462s

Some random SQLite benchmark
ZFS only
fillseq      :      38.833 micros/op;                 
fillseqsync  :    1391.493 micros/op;               
fillseqbatch :       1.954 micros/op;                 
fillrandom   :      62.420 micros/op;                 
fillrandsync :    1406.985 micros/op;               
fillrandbatch :      36.149 micros/op;                
overwrite    :      84.639 micros/op;    1.3 MB/s     
overwritebatch :      68.687 micros/op;               
readrandom   :      58.584 micros/op;                 
readseq      :      42.483 micros/op;                 
fillrand100K :     867.440 micros/op;  1           
fillseq100K  :     851.599 micros/op;  11          
readseq      :       0.461 micros/op;                 
readrand100K :      99.846 micros/op;              

ZFS over LUKS
fillseq      :      38.453 micros/op;                 
fillseqsync  :    1454.040 micros/op;               
fillseqbatch :       2.035 micros/op;                 
fillrandom   :      63.107 micros/op;                 
fillrandsync :    1531.823 micros/op;               
fillrandbatch :      36.717 micros/op;                
overwrite    :      82.490 micros/op;    1.3 MB/s     
overwritebatch :      68.175 micros/op;               
readrandom   :      46.421 micros/op;                 
readseq      :      42.086 micros/op;                 
fillrand100K :     849.366 micros/op;  11          
fillseq100K  :     837.989 micros/op;  11          
readseq      :       0.461 micros/op;                 
readrand100K :      98.598 micros/op;              

In summary
Looking at just raw IO performance with FIO, we see quite a big gap: both read and write bandwidth seems to be down by ~30%. However, in real-world uses involving lots of interleaved IO and computation, the difference basically washes out.

So nominally zero cost in your benchmarked applications.  What's the benefit?

@JimL. As written:  zfs send-ing encrypted datasets to untrusted backup storage.

@OleTange Does zfs send --raw not work for you? From the man page: -w, --raw ... For encrypted datasets, send data exactly as it exists on disk. This allows backups to be taken even if encryption keys are not currently loaded.  The backup may then be received on an untrusted machine since that machine will not have the encryption keys to read the protected data
